# uwp compact overlay on a specific position on screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, picture-in-picture

In uwp we can open compact overlay mode with following code.

```
await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
```

but this always opens on top right side and if we open multiple new windows then all of them overlap each other, how can we specify to open at a specific position on the screen apart from top right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can we specify to open at a specific position on the screen apart from top right?

Currently, UWP does not provide such API to open  `CompactOverlay` view at a specific  position. We can only custom the size of CompactOverlay view with the following method.

```
public IAsyncOperation<bool> TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode viewMode, ViewModePreferences viewModePreferences);
```

If you do want this feature, you are welcome to ask on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) .

Comment: UV link: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/31916818-api-to-set-where-compact-overlay-window-is-shown